# Detecting OS on PHP is running

Tags: php, locale

I got a problem with current project I'm working on and I need some help:

1. Functions `strtoupper()`, `mb_strtoupper()`, etc are not working
2. I need to set correct locale to make them work
3. For that I need to know OS on PHP is runing, because for Windows correct command is `setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");` or `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian_Russia.1251");` and for others (I don't know for all others or not) is `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU');`

BUT all methods of OS detection I found uses `strupper()`/`strtolower()` to detect OS... So now I am in some confusion. What should I do. How to detect OS...

By the way, performance is critical and if someone knows good and fast method to detect OS or set correct locale it will be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setlocale` supports passing of multiple locales, it will pick the first one that is available. So:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'rus', 'Russian_Russia.1251', 'ru_RU');
```

This works cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks that's it! I think I have to read mans again :) But there is another problem: now setlocale is correct, but strtoupper not working... For example for word 'мама' strtoupper returned 'УаУа' and mb_strtoupper returned 'мама'. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea about the incorrect conversion. I don't even know what the correct result should be.

Answer (score 1):

The `PHP_OS`
 Constant is what you're looking for - [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)

But what methods did you actually look at yourself, and what was wrong with them?

Answer (score 1):

`phpinfo()` is the way to go. It gives you all you need.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your way. All is simple:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.CP1251', 'rus_RUS.CP1251', 'Russian_Russia.1251');

// ru_RU.CP1251 for FreeBSD
// rus_RUS.CP1251 for Linux
// Russian_Russia.1251 for Windows
```